# Editable TextView with Second NavBar - Text appears, but too late

Tags: iphone, keyboard, uitextview, uinavigationbar

Editable TextView with Second NavBar - Text appears, but too late.

The app has a single Navigation Controller. 
I have an iPhone App that has basically three levels.

1. Level 1 - Table with category Names
2. Level 2 - Table with list of items for selected category
3. Level 3 - Tabbed View with several views, including UITextView for details of item
   One to these Tabbed Views with a TextView is editable.

   When the user taps in the editable TextView the KeyBoard
   appears. User can type in the TextView. Characters appear
   as they are typed.

   At the top of this Level 3 TextView there is a NavBar (present for all 3 levels with
   changes) with a BackButton and a "home->Level1" button on the right.

All works just fine until in the editable TextView I add a second NavigationBar
below the existing NavBar. This second NavBar has two buttons
as well. They are Save/Cancel.

When I click these Save and Cancel buttons the correct action
methods are reached. All is perfect with one exception, The text 
which is typed does not appear in the TextView until either
the Save or the Cancel button is touched. The relevant Button setup and 
action methods in my `TabViewController.m` are below. I need to persist this
data.

I thought that getting a Notification from the TextView and the action handleTextChange would do the trick, but no luck. I am stuck.

```
.........
- (void)loadView {

    self.myTextView = [[UITextView alloc] init];
    self.myTextView.delegate = self;

    self.view   = self.myTextView;
    //UITextViewTextDidChangeNotification   
    NSNotificationCenter *nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [nc addObserver:self
    selector:@selector(handleTextChange:) 
    name:UITextViewTextDidChangeNotification
    object:nil];
    NSLog(@"Registered DG_HandleChangeTextNotification with notification center.");

}

- (void)handleTextChange:(NSNotification * )note 
{
    [self.myTextView  setNeedsDisplay] ;
    NSLog(@"...Handled Text Change.");
}


- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    // provide my own Done/Save button to dismiss the keyboard

    saveNavigationBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
    saveNavigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
    UINavigationItem *doneItem = [[UINavigationItem alloc] init];   
    doneItem.title = @"My Notes";

    UIBarButtonItem *doneItemButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
      initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemSave 
        target:self action:@selector(saveAction:)];
    UIBarButtonItem *cancelItemButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
      initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self 
        action:@selector(cancelAction:)];

    [doneItem setRightBarButtonItem:doneItemButton animated:NO];
    [doneItem setLeftBarButtonItem:cancelItemButton animated:NO];
    [saveNavigationBar pushNavigationItem:doneItem animated:NO];

    [self.view addSubview:saveNavigationBar];

    [doneItem release];
    [cancelItemButton release];
    [doneItemButton release];
}

- (void)saveAction:(id)sender
{
    // finish typing text/dismiss the keyboard by removing it as the first responder

        self.text = self.myTextView.text;
    [self.saveNavigationBar removeFromSuperview];

    [self.myTextView  resignFirstResponder]; 

}

- (void)cancelAction:(id)sender
{
    [self.saveNavigationBar removeFromSuperview];

    [self.myTextView  resignFirstResponder];

}
```

Comment: The Second NavBar was hiding the area of the UITextEdit
such that I had to type about four lines before I saw the text. I believe I need to lower the height of the UITextEdit by 44 pixels.

Answer (score 0):

The Second NavBar was hiding the area of the UITextEdit
such that I had to type about four lines before I saw the text. I believe
I need to lower the height of the UITextEdit by 44 pixels.